# Extracting subset of data with inner join to itself

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have data in the following format and want to extract the records that have year = 2013 and 2014 and 2015 for a Symbol. (ie those 3 years, not 2 of, not 4)

The first one below (FLWS) fits but the next one (FCCY) only has 2013 and 2014 but not 15 so i don't want it in the end set.  Further down DDD and MMM have 2012 to 2105 and I just want the 2013-15 data from them.

I can't figure out the inner join needed to extract the sets of 3 records for 2013, 14 and 15.  Any help appreciated 
Thanks

```
Symbol  Exchange    Date        Year
FLWS    NAS         2013-05-01  2015
FLWS    NAS         2013-05-01  2014
FLWS    NAS         2013-05-01  2013
FCCY    NAS         2013-05-01  2014
FCCY    NAS         2013-05-01  2013
SRCE    NAS         2013-05-01  2014
SRCE    NAS         2013-05-01  2013
SRCE    NAS         2013-05-01  2012
FNHC    NAS         2013-05-01  2014
FNHC    NAS         2013-05-01  2013
DDD     NYS         2013-05-01  2015
DDD     NYS         2013-05-01  2014
DDD     NYS         2013-05-01  2013
DDD     NYS         2013-05-01  2012
MMM     NYS         2013-05-01  2015
MMM     NYS         2013-05-01  2014
MMM     NYS         2013-05-01  2013
MMM     NYS         2013-05-01  2012
JOBS    NAS         2013-05-01  2014
JOBS    NAS         2013-05-01  2013
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understood your question

```
Declare @Table table (Symbol varchar(25),Exchange varchar(25),Date Date,Year int)
Insert Into @Table (Symbol,Exchange,Date,Year) values
('FLWS','NAS','2013-05-01',2015),
('FLWS','NAS','2013-05-01',2014),
('FLWS','NAS','2013-05-01',2013),
('FCCY','NAS','2013-05-01',2014),
('FCCY','NAS','2013-05-01',2013),
('SRCE','NAS','2013-05-01',2014),
('SRCE','NAS','2013-05-01',2013),
('SRCE','NAS','2013-05-01',2012),
('FNHC','NAS','2013-05-01',2014),
('FNHC','NAS','2013-05-01',2013),
('DDD','NYS','2013-05-01',2015),
('DDD','NYS','2013-05-01',2014),
('DDD','NYS','2013-05-01',2013),
('DDD','NYS','2013-05-01',2012),
('MMM','NYS','2013-05-01',2015),
('MMM','NYS','2013-05-01',2014),
('MMM','NYS','2013-05-01',2013),
('MMM','NYS','2013-05-01',2012),
('JOBS','NAS','2013-05-01',2014),
('JOBS','NAS','2013-05-01',2013)

Select A.* 
 From @Table A
 Join (Select Symbol,Hits=count(Distinct Year),MinYear=min(Year) From @Table Group By Symbol) B on (A.Symbol=B.Symbol and B.Hits=3 and B.MinYear=2013)
 Order By Symbol,Year
```

Returns

```
Symbol  Exchange    Date        Year
FLWS    NAS         2013-05-01  2013
FLWS    NAS         2013-05-01  2014
FLWS    NAS         2013-05-01  2015
```

Comment: Thank you John - I am trying to get all of the sets of 3 which woudl include FLWS, SRCE, DDD and MMM

Comment: Am using your basis here to help me get the sets of 3 - thank you

Comment: @BrianD Then just remove  and B.MinYear=2013  ... If I understand your goal.

Comment: Thank You for the reply John

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:
The inner query will just list the symbols which appears 3 times in database. The outer query will use this symbol names to select all the data only for the listed symbols.

```
select * from table
where symbol in ( select Symbol from table
where year in (2013, 2014, 2015)
group by symbol
having count (distinct year) = 3)
```

Comment: you need `count(distinct year) = 3 and year in (2013, 2014, 2015)` for your inner `where` clause, but good answer

Comment: Thanks - what you describe above is what i want but am getting an An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause error message.  Working at it now

Comment: thats true, you need to use having with group by. see the edited answer

Comment: pls mark the answer as right answer if this helped you